# FTP Shell Script does not working

Tags: linux, shell, ftp, ksh

I want to download file from server using FTP.

Here's my script code. (myscript.sh)

```
#!/bin/ksh
ftp -n $1 << END
user $2 $3
lcd $4
get $5
bye
EOF
```

After writing script and run, It does not working.

```
sh myscript.sh 111.222.333.444 testuser test /myfolder/src/data/ DATA20140419.txt
```

shell display this message : 
usage lcd local-directory

What's the problem in my script code?

Comment: If you're having to use the `sh myscript...` to launch this script, did you do `chmod 755 myscript.sh` ? This will make it directly executable, and you won't need to use `sh ...`, which may be complicating your issue, as @7heo.tk mentions below. (Looks like  your script should work, otherwise). Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I already change permission. If i didn't change permission, shell display "permission denied" message. Thanks for your comment and i will try @7heo.tk's solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved this problem.

The reason is, encoding.

I wrote script code using windows, run in unix.

**I missed that difference of "ENTER".**

UNIX's enter is \n

but, Windows enter is \r\n

so, **Without encoding script code, error must be occured.**

Most of windows editer supply encoding option. (UNIX, DOS, WINDOWS style.)

If you use unix editor(ex, vi) you don't need to encoding.

**Addition.**

1. If you didn't set remote directory(cd) or local directory(lcd),
   the source and destnation is default folder.
2. END, EOF don't effect script code. you can use any string.
3. To run shell script, you must use "sh" keyword. "./" can't run shell script.

Comment: What you call "ENTER" is called [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline). Aside from that, the points 2 and 3 from your "addition" are wrong: `EOF` is **NOT** ending the heredocument string, it is sent to the ftp client. Since `EOF` is not a known ftp command, it is bogus, and therefore is ignored by the your ftp client. Since it also is the last instruction, it does not cause the script to "bug" (try to echo something after your `EOF`, you'll see). Also, to run the shell script, you can invoke it using `./scriptname`. It's the whole point of using a shebang.

Answer (score 2):

Try to start the command via : `./myscript.sh` and not via `sh ./myscript.sh`: You are using a shebang specifying `ksh`. Invoking `sh` directly will most certainly "bypass" the shebang (it will, unless sh reads it and starts ksh - and that depends on your sh implementation), and will not invoke `ksh` as wanted.

Also, you should not end your [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) with `EOF` if it expects `END`. Another point is that you probably want to put all your arguments (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) between quotes, so you are sure that their value is not separated by spaces (as in `"$1"`, `"$2"`, and so on).

However, I doubt that this is causing the error message. The point is, I cannot replicate your error locally, even if I copy/paste your script. Then, I cannot tell what is causing this error message to appear, since an empty `lcd` argument does output the current local directory, on my local FTP client (Debian).

The only answer I can give you is that prior to the `get`, you should `cd` to the correct directory (the `get` command should only contain the path of the file *in the current* directory). Then your script shall be:

```
#!/bin/ksh
ftp -n $1 << END
user $2 $3
lcd $4
cd $(dirname $5)
get $(basename $5)
bye
END
```

and you should use it like this:

```
$ ./myscript <server> <user> <passwd> <localdir> <remotedir/file>
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript 1.2.3.4 7heo secret . /path/to/remote/file
```

Comment: FYI, you can do what you are trying to do on one line using ncftpget.  See http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpget.html

Comment: I am trying to answer the question. I doubt that I can do it with ncFTP. I guess you maybe wanted to leave a comment on the question itself? :)

Comment: I will try your solution tomorrow. (I can't connect my company's FTP server in my home. :(  ) Thanks for your answer.